# Getting multiple events per click

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting two events per click on an events object like so:

```js
Template.testbed.events({
  'click button': function (event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
});


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#edit{{level.ruleNumber}}_{{level.levelNumber}}" name="edit{{level.ruleNumber}}_{{level.levelNumber}}">Edit</button>
```

When clicking it spits out:

> jQuery.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timeStamp:
>   175016.73500000002, jQuery111209352032851355545: true, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, …}
>
> jQuery.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", timeStamp:
>   175016.73500000002, jQuery111209352032851355545: true, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, …}

How do I get it to register each click only once instead of repeatedly?

Updated:  I'm only having this issue on recursively pulling entries.  Each entry in a collection can be a child of another entry, and have children of their own.  To make it show up I make it list entries without children and recursively recall the same template.

```
{{#let comparenum=rule.ruleNumber}}
{{#each rule in parent.rules}}
{{#if equals rule.parentRule comparenum}}
{{> rulesetRule rule=rule parent=parent}}
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
{{/let}}
```

Entry A has no parent, Entry B lists A as parent, and Entry C lists B.  Clicking C shows me clicking it 3 times when I only hit it once.  This happens for each button for C consistently.  Same as getting two clicks per click for buttons in the B entry's call.

Why would this make each button in the recalled listEntry template get clicked the number of times it's been ran to reach it?

Comment: Show your HTML for this template, please.

Comment: All buttons on the page have a double click report in the console.  Posted one example.

Comment: To prevent events from bubbling-up. Try using `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` before `console.log`.

Comment: @SaugatAcharya There is no bubbling: in HTML buttons don't have nested elements.

Comment: @Styx Yes that is true.

Comment: @CodeDragonDM Could you replace `console.log(event)` with `console.log(event.currentTarget)`?

Comment: I did, and it just spits out the HTML for the button I clicked into the console twice.

Comment: Well, it seems we would need to see more code then. Otherwise, it isn't clear, where the problem lays.

Comment: If you're using chrome, try `monitorEvents(yourButton, 'click')` and see if it's something about the html or the js

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find out it's related to another problem that makes less sense.  Will update when I find out what I can share.

Comment: Found the issue but I don't know why it's causing an issue to begin with: Putting it as a new edit.  Something to do with collection entries having a related-to parent.